# Fabric: check if user is connected to Twitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm using Fabric and I want to check, from my android application if the user is connected on the Twitter application or in the browser. So I have to check the active session. For that I use this code:

```
    TwitterSession twitterSession = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
```

And this is how Fabric added the code in the `onCreate` of the `MainActivity`:

```
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(twitterKey, twitterSecretKey);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
```

Is Fabric initialized correctly?

Why I'm always getting null in the `twitterSession`? Even if I test it in the  `onCreate` of the `MainActivity`?

Comment: twitterAuthClient = new TwitterAuthClient(); also you need to

Comment: @GIBINTHOMAS where have I to use twitterAuthClient?

Comment: may be you havn't autorised the user from what i understood check with the below code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rTry this

```
iv_tweet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                twitterAuthClient.authorize(LoginActivity.this, new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
                        Log.e("success1", "success1");
                        final TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();

                    }

                    @Override

                    public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

and  in onActivity result

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == TwitterAuthConfig.DEFAULT_AUTH_REQUEST_CODE) {
            twitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

    }
```

If that doesn't meet your need please comment below

Comment: Sorry but I'm getting the same problem

Comment: is that loging your user via the  twittter app? your app secret ,Key everything you have created ?

Comment: Yes I'm new to android dev. So if I understood well, the fabric initialization should be in the onCreate but the code on your answer should be on the onclick. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yeah perfect when you call the onclick the code which i posted trigger the twitter app .Can you make sure the twitter app is installed in your device also the initialisation[Twitttr and fabric ] part should be in the activity you are clicking the button and not on the launcher app as fabric sets the sdks on the launcher actvity in the first place

Comment: Will your code always ask for authorization in the twitter app? And if the user is not the connected, will this redirect it to the login screen?

Comment: As per my knowledge thats a world wide issue of reauthorising each time in twitter.You can manage by the autoLogin api  accesstoken and session handling or by using a singleton concept.which we create for the same.

Comment: The click on my button open the twitter app on the authorization screen. When I click on "Allow", my app crash with this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=140, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity. Its a NullPointerException

Comment: Also when I debug the success or failure of your code are never called. I think that after the click on "Allow" the application goes to the onActivityResult but it found a null object (that I think is the session)

Comment: To do it on the onActivityResult?

Comment: i have changed the answer

Comment: I'm testing... :)

Comment: I tested with the two modes: when I'm already logged in twitter I'm getting the authorization then after clicking on "allow" I'm not having the error :) (I have just to work on the share) also if I'm not connected I'm redirected to the loggin Twitter screen :) Thank you sooooo much!

Comment: So you tell me that the asking for authorization is an issue from twitter? Isn't it?

Comment: :) for the support if i come to know otherwise i will let you know.

Comment: Can you please take a look on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091436/tweets-are-not-posted-using-fabric ?