# Tweets are not posted using Fabric

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I’m trying to post tweets form my android application. After the user authorize my application to use its account, normally the tweet have to be posted automatically but in my case, nothing happened. The authentication part works fine, the problem is in the share part. Using Fabric, this is how I post the tweet:

```
TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
StatusesService statusesService = Twitter.getApiClient(session).getStatusesService();
statusesService.update(message, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, String.valueOf(new Callback<Tweet>() {
@Override
public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {
Log.d("Tweet", "post success");
}
@Override
public void failure(TwitterException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}));
```

When I debug the `success` and the `failure`.
I got any error, no exception, but nothing is posted.
What is wrong with what I’m doing?

Comment: Just to tweet post from the sgned in user?You can simply use intent

Comment: I want to post tweets from my application but with the connected user account

Comment: @GIBINTHOMAS can you explain more please?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking this its a lil bit old code

```
 try {


            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.setType("image/jpeg");
            intent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            commonAction.showToast("No twitter App Installed in device");
            Log.v("VM", "Exception while sending image on" + "com.twitter.android.PostActivity" + " " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Why is the StatusesService doesn't match in my case?

Comment: pardon what do you mean/

Comment: I mean that why have I to use intent instead of StatusesService? Is the intent more adapted on this case than StatusesService?

Comment: i am not aware of that for simple posting tweet with your data you could use intent

Comment: It works but I want to post it directly, without asking the user if the share have to be via message or tweet. I want to post it directly after the "allow" is successful

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77745/send-tweet-automatically-using-an-intent/77748   :(